# Gradient descent loss increase

Tags: neural-networks, gradient-descent

I am following the [CS231n NN case study](https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-case-study/) — a derivation of gradient descent for a simple network with a single hidden layer.

I have followed the rest of the tutorial and have confidence that the derivations are correct.

However, when I run their code (after “The full code looks very similar:”), I encounter increases to the loss function.

How is this possible? Do I have an error in my code? Or is it possible for the loss function to increase? I have seen a reference to loss increases depending on step size…

Comment: The duplicate explains that if the step size is *too large*, the loss can *increase*. While it's possible that you have a bug in your code, but debugging is not on-topic here. In any event, it's impossible for someone to debug code that they can't see.